# Consider the sequence of functions and compute the limit of the integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

Consider the sequence of functions $f_n:[0,1] \to R$ given by

$$f_n(x) = \frac{e^{-(n + x^2)}}{n^2 + x}$$
for $x \in [0,1]$ and $n \geq 1$

Compute $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x) dx$$

Maybe I'm overthinking this, but it seems like all I have to do is compute the integral of $f_n(x)$ and then take the limit. However, I am wondering if there is more to it since I can't seem to find an easy way to compute the integral. Can anyone lend me a hand?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you REALLY try to compute it? I think this is a classical example of interchanginf limit and integral.

Comment: Hint: The sequence is monotone.

Comment: @TitoEliatron yes. I don't see a way to u-sub since the part of e and the denominator are different. I'm not really seeing a way to go about it. You mention bringing the limit inside. This would give me 0/0, which can't be done. So I'm still very unsure.

Comment: @Chris I don't see how that helps me here.

Comment: Do you know something about Lebesgue intergal/measure?

Comment: @TitoEliatron I was wondering if it had to do with that. Here's the thing: my professor has not covered Lebesgue integration yet. In fact, we technically should NOT have watched the video on Lebesgue measure for this assignment, but I watched it in advance. Are you by chance familiar with the Princeton Real Analysis book by Stein? I'm trying to figure out what section the material needed for this problem would be covered so I know how far ahead I should go. My guess as to why I'm confused is because we haven't covered the material yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to give a solution avoiding any reference to Lebesgue.

First, observe that $f_n(x)\ge 0$ for all $n$ and $x\in[0,1]$, so $$\int_0^1f_n(x)dx\ge 0.$$

Secondly, $f_n(x)\le \frac{1}{n^2+x}$ (observe that $n+x^2>0$ so $e^{-(n+x^2)}\le e^0=1$), so
$$\int_0^1f_n(x)dx\le \int_0^1 \frac{1}{n^2+x}dx=\log|n^2+x|\bigg|_0^1=\log(n^2+1)-\log(n^2)=\log(1+1/n^2).$$

Putting al together, $$0\le\int_0^1f_n(x)dx\le\log(1+1/n^2).$$

But $\lim_{n}\log(1+1/n^2)=0$.
So the squeeze theorem assures that $$\exists\lim_n \int_0^1 f_n(x)dx=0.$$

Comment: This does make sense. I still want to ask my question about the Lebesgue integration/measure way of doing it. There are other problems that I have to do that are similar to this, but they also have to do with uniform convergence, pointwise convergence, etc. Is there a way to do these with Lesbegue techniques? If so, then I would want to spend more time trying to find it in my book so I know what material I have to watch.

Answer (score 0):

$$f_n(x)=\frac{e^{-(n+x^2)}}{n^2+x}=\frac{e^{-n}}{n^2}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{1+x/n^2}$$
now if we make the substitution $u=x/n^2\Rightarrow dx=n^2du$ and our integral becomes:
$$I_n=\int\limits_0^{1/n^2}e^{-n}\frac{e^{-n^4u^2}}{1+u}du=e^{-n}\int\limits_0^{1/n^2}\frac{(e^{-u^2})^{n^4}}{1+u}du$$
Now remember that the average of a function is defined as:
$$\hat{f}_{[a,b]}=\frac1{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)dx$$ now if $b\to a^+$ it is clear that $\hat{f}\to f(a)$ In our case the range of the interval is tending to zero, in other words:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\int\limits_0^{1/n^2}\frac{e^{-n^4u^2}}{1+u}du=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{u\to0^+}\frac{e^{-n^4u^2}}{1+u^2}$$
maybe you can use this?